# Dynamically adding scripts to IE with(?) appendchild

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, appendchild

I have built [this](http://www.s-maof.com/shorts/shorts_table.php) page.

The page contains a table which when you click on a specific row -loads a script that draws a specific graph.

This means I need to append multiple numbers of scripts (and not at the same time - depends on the user).

I have used Jquery's **appendchild** but have noticed that it doesn't work well in IE (loads the first one and then gets stuck).

I have already looked through posts here that stated the same thing and tried them..

I tried using:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script1.text = myscript;
body.appendChild(script);
```

AND

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'jQuery/head/dynamic_graph.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

and Even

```
$(script).appendTo($("#graphMain" + id));
```

still works on every browser except for IE...

any suggestions?

Edit:

also tried

```
$.getScript("jQuery/head/dynamic_info.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    });
```

and IE failed to preform..

Comment: I'd rewrite your title so people browsing can see what the question is (currently it makes no sense) - you will likely get more views/answers. I've edited your post to improve grammar/spelling but I have no idea what the intended title is.

Comment: WHY are you trying to add a script dynamically, instead of just linking to it directly? What you should be doing is loading prepared functions when the page loads, and calling those functions dynamically when new rows are added.

Comment: Please change the variable name from "script" to something else like "myscript"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, what's wrong with naming a variable script?

Comment: It is just confusing to the next developer that has to view this code.  same would apply to the "head" and "body" variable - it is simply my opinion, and I know that is not what is asked for and it is only a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

thanks guys, 
But after 10 hours of hairs plumings..
I figured it out..
apperantly - IE prevent from attaching multiple scripts with the same name -
so I changed the name of each script to a unique name.

I used

```
$.getScript("jQuery/head/dynamic_info"+id+".js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
});
```

where Id is the uniqe number (the row number in tthis case)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load external scripts, and you're using jQuery, it seems the wisest solution would be to use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load the files in rather than trying to roll your own solution using `.appendChild` or any other similar method.

Comment: hi Jonathatan, I am using $.getScript to load the scripts (it's myScript in the example). But after its loaded, I use appendchild  to include the script in the code.. do you have other suggestions how to do so?

Comment: @user1392330 You don't have to append anything. `$.getScript` executes the code for you when it loads it. Nothing to append. Can you share an example of the code you're trying to bring into the document?

Comment: Thanks, tried it and it also gets stuck! what else can I try? I updated the qestion..

Comment: You need to be more specific than "IE got stuck" or "IE failed". What does your network traffic look like? You can watch it by pressing F12, going to the Network tab, clicking "Start Recording", call `$.getScript()`, and then hitting "Stop Recording". Then examine your logs. Does the file get loaded? Does it get executed? Try putting an `alert('Loaded');` in the top of it for testing.